# angular listen for changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

NgOnChanges update table when changes is detected causes infinite service call , which I dont have any idea why. Maybe someone can help. Thanks.

I have parent component TableMultiSortComponent and I passed output EventEmitter which is the table data .

The event or the output from EventEmitter is passed to child component which I will use the pagesize , pageindex etc to query as you can see on the dataServiceEvent on the child component.

And then the output of the request is dealsListData which I pass back from child to parent as data to be populated to the table.

It should update table when there is changes that is why I put it on ngOnchanges which is the initTableMultiSort but right now it is updating the table infinitely , it should only update once if there is changes

[image]

#the table data that I am passing from parent component to child component , this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);  , this is what I emit cause I will be needing the pageindex, size etc.

[image]

#HTML CODE - Parent Component

```
<mat-card *ngIf="table !== undefined">
  <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="table.dataSource" matMultiSort (matSortChange)="table.onSortEvent()"> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of table.columns" [matColumnDef]="column.id">
      <mat-header-cell class="table-multi-sort-header" *matHeaderCellDef [mat-multi-sort-header]="column.id"> 
        <div>{{column.name}}</div> 
        <div class="sub-text">{{getColumnSubtitle(column.id)}}</div>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <ng-container *ngIf="column.id !== 'action'; then col; else actionCol"></ng-container>
          <ng-template #col>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-default [cellData]="row" [id]="column.id" [subId]="getColumnSubId(column.id)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-default>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #actionCol>
            <app-table-multi-sort-cell-action [rowData]="row" [actions]="getActions(column.id)" (actionClickEvent)="clickTableAction($event,row)"></app-table-multi-sort-cell-action>
          </ng-template>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="table.displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: table.displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table> 
  <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</mat-card>
```

#ts code- parent component

```
export class TableMultiSortComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableOptions:any;
  @Input() tableData:any = [];
  @Input() isClientSide:boolean = false;
  @Input() isLoading: boolean = false;
  @Output() tableActionsEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() dataServiceEvent = new EventEmitter<any>() ;
  @ViewChild(MatMultiSort, { static: false }) sort: MatMultiSort;
  
  tableConfig: any = TABLE_MULTI_SORT_OPTIONS.DEFAULT;
  table:TableData<any>;
  displayedColumns: any;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.initTableMultiSort();
  }

  initTableMultiSort(){
    this.tableConfig = {
      ...this.tableConfig,
      ...this.tableOptions
    }
    
    this.table = new TableData<any>(this.tableConfig.columns,this.tableConfig.sortParams);
    this.table.pageSize = this.tableConfig.pageSize;
    this.table.pageIndex = this.tableConfig.pageIndex;
    this.table.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });
    this.table.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.getData(); });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.table.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.isClientSide);
      this.getData();
    },0);
    
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {  
    if (changes.tableData && changes.tableData.currentValue){  
      console.log("changes" , changes)
      this.initTableMultiSort()
    }
  }

  getData(){
    this.table.totalElements = 1;
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    this.table.pageSize = 10;
    this.table.data = this.tableData;
    if(this.dataServiceEvent) {
      this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);
      
    }
  }
```

#child component HTML code

```
  <app-table-multi-sort  (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="dealsListData" (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

#child component ts code

```
   export class DealsTransactionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() transactionId: any = 2;
  @Input() transactionName: string = '-';
  @ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
  private currentTableConfig: TableData<any>;


  dealsListData: any;
  tableOptions: any;
  @Input() transaction: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  private _destroyed$ = new Subject();
  totalDeals : number;
  accountId: any;
  searchInput: string;
  table: any;
  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private dealService: DealService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private route: Router,
    
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const currentAccountDetails = localStorage.getItem('currAcct') as any;
    if (currentAccountDetails) {
      this.accountId = JSON.parse(currentAccountDetails).accountId;
    }

    this.tableOptions = {
      columns:[
        {id:'name',name:'Deal Name',subId:'type', subtitle:'Deal Type'},
        {id:'annualRentProposed',name:'Annual Rent (Proposed)', subId: 'annualRentCurrent', subtitle:'Annual Rent (Proposed)'},
        {id:'firmTermRemain',name:'Firm Term Remaining', subId: 'firmTermAdded', subtitle:'(Current)'},
        {id:'maxTerm',name:'Max Available Term'},
        {id:'cash',name:'Cash Contribution'},
        {id:'action', name: 'Actions', actions:[
          {icon:'file_copy', name:'Copy', class:'primary-color'},
          {icon:'delete', name: 'Delete', class:'mat-error'},
          {icon:'forward', name: 'For Approval', class:'primary-color'}
        ]}
      ]
    }
  }

  dataServiceEvent(item) {
    this.table = item;
    if(this.table) {
      this._pageEventMyList();
    }
  }

  private _pageEventMyList() {
    if (!this.shouldLoadData(this.currentTableConfig, this.table)) {
      return;
    }
    this.currentTableConfig = this.table;
    this.searchInput = '';
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.dealsListData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.dealsListData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.totalDeals = res.items.length;
          this.dealsListData = res.items;
          console.log("this.dealsListData" , this.dealsListData)
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
  private shouldLoadData(oldTableConfig: TableData<any>, tableConfig: TableData<any>): boolean {
    if (!oldTableConfig) {
      return true;
    }
    return oldTableConfig.pageIndex !== tableConfig.pageIndex
      || oldTableConfig.pageSize !== tableConfig.pageSize
      || oldTableConfig.sortParams !== tableConfig.sortParams
      || JSON.stringify(oldTableConfig.sortParams) !== JSON.stringify(tableConfig.sortParams)
      || JSON.stringify(oldTableConfig.sortDirs) !== JSON.stringify(tableConfig.sortDirs);
  }

  createDeal() {
    this.route.navigateByUrl(`deals/detail/${this.transactionId}~create`, {
      state: { data: this.transaction },
    });
    localStorage.removeItem('breadCrumbsPath');
    const breadCrumbsPath = [
      {
        text: 'My transactions',
        link: '/transactions',
      },
      {
        text: this.transactionName,
        link: `/transactions/overview/${this.transactionId}`,
      },
    ];
    localStorage.setItem('breadCrumbsPath', JSON.stringify(breadCrumbsPath));
  }

  copyDeal(id: number) {
    const data  = { id : id }
    this.duplicateDeal(data)
  }
  deleteDeal(id: number) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService.delete(id)
      .pipe(finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false;}))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.dealsListData = this.dealsListData.filter((x) => x.id !== id);
          this.notificationService.showSuccess('Deal been removed successfully.');
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
      });
  }
  duplicateDeal(data: any) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService.duplicate(data)
      .pipe( finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false;}))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          let copyData = {
            ...this.dealsListData.filter((x) => x.id === data.id),
          };
          copyData.name = copyData.name + '(copy)';
          copyData.id = this.dealsListData[this.dealsListData.length - 1].id + 1;
          this.notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully duplicated.' );
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
      });
  }

  approveDeal(data: any) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .approve(data)
      .pipe(finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; }))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was approved');
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emitting `this.table` whenever you call `getData` in the `TableMultiSortComponent` which happens in `ngOnInit` for the first time.

This event emission (I suppose) triggers the actual data fetch in the parent component, in the `tableActions` method (could not see the implementation of this method in the code you included). This method is probably doing something similar to `_pageEventMyList` that gets data from the API and sets the `dealsListData` property on the `TableMultiSortComponent` (`[tableData]="dealsListData"`).

This in turn, triggers your `onChange` in the `TableMultiSortComponent` and also passes your `if` check (the `tableData` is actually changed). From `onChange`, you call `initTableMultiSort` that reinitializes `this.table` and emits it with `this.dataServiceEvent.emit(this.table);`. This makes all go into a cycle.

I recommend to implement some extra checks to make sure you are not triggering data reload if the table configuration is the same.

In short, it looks like you use the table for providing you data about the `pageIndex`, `pageSize`, `sortParams` and `sortDirs`, so I suggest to keep information about the value of these properties when you try to load data again. Compare them, and if something is changed, then fetch data

```
  private currentTableConfig: TableData<any>;

  private _pageEventMyList() {
    if (!shouldLoadData(currentTableConfig, this.table)) {
      return;
    }
    this.currentTableConfig = this.table;
    this.searchInput = '';
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.dealsListData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.dealsListData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.totalDeals = res.items.length;
          this.dealsListData = res.items;
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

and the new `shouldLoadData` method performs the checks:

```
private shouldLoadData(oldTableConfig: TableData<any>, tableConfig: TableData<any>): boolean {
  if (!oldTableConfig) {
    return true;
  }
  return oldTableConfig.pageIndex !== tableConfig.pageIndex
    || oldTableConfig.pageSize !== tableConfig.pageSize
    || JSON.stringify(oldTableConfig.sortParams) !== JSON.stringify(tableConfig.sortParams)
    || JSON.stringify(oldTableConfig.sortDirs) !== JSON.stringify(tableConfig.sortDirs);
}
```

Disclaimer for using `JSON.stringify`:

This works, but it is not optimal. If you have another third party library installed, like `lodash`, you can go for `_.isEqual` instead (or something similar, that will compare the array contents for you).

Comment: Hi Sir , do you have some example fixes or implementation based on my code and based on your suggestion that I can try. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by some extra checks  Sir , this has been bugging me for days ?

Comment: can you add more detail to what you mean as table configuration is the same or not . thanls

Comment: @JellynAng See my updated answer for a potential solution.

Comment: Hi Sir , so I wont be changing anything from my TableMultiSortComponent  ?

Comment: This is more like a workaround than a full solution, so these should be the only changes you need to break the cycle.

Comment: Sir , what if I have a function or action to delete the data on component deals-transaction.component.ts , how to refresh the data on the table ? should I always call _pageEventMyList everytime I delete , update data ?

Comment: I have update my DealsTransactionComponent above Sir

Comment: Hi , I have just a questionSir

Comment: Why is that the currentTableConfig has the same value with the this.table I click the table multi sort ?

Comment: I applied your code and it stops the loop but when there are changes it was not detect on the parents ngOnchanges Sier